# PDO not outputing correct row count

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following table and rows:

```
tasks
id       name
===================
1       create user
2       delete user
3       update user
```

I am trying to get a rowcount on how many tasks i have in that table. I have the following function

```
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM tasks");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->cnt;
            return $result;
```

It just keeps returning 0, but if i take that same query and run it directly on the db it works fine. Anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you're pointing at the right host/database/table?

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying it like this

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM tasks");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
return $result->cnt;
```